# How Can I Serialize a particular Expression, Func, Lambda to a String with its values?

Tags: caching, lambda, expression

I'm trying to cache queries, using this function:

```
public static string GenerateCacheKey(string className, string methodName, params object[] parameters)
    {
        string[] strings = parameters.Select(p => p==null ? "null" : p.ToString()).ToArray();
        return string.Format("{0}.{1}({2})", className, methodName, string.Join(",", strings));
    }
```

I have a repository with a method signature like this:

```
IList<TEntity> List(int? page, int? pageSize,
                            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate,
                            Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> sort);
```

An actual call to this might look like this:

```
var activeItemsForUser =
                _itemRepository.List(null, null, 
i => i.Active && i.userId=userId, null).ToList();
```

The problem is that the string cache key generated for i=>i.Active&&i.userId=userId for userId 123 and userId 456 are the same.  Both just have the string "value" in place of the userId value.

How can I serialize the actual expression with its variable values into a unique string per expression for use in my GenerateCacheKey method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this probably isnt too helpfull but...

you could make a specification class and use that as the cache Key instead?

```
public class ActiveUserSpec : ISpecification<User>
{
    int userId; 
    public ActiveUser(int userId){
       this.userId=userId;    
    }

    public Expression<Func<User, bool>> Match()
    {
        retuen u => u.Active && u.userId == userId;
    }
    public string AsString()
    {
        return GetType().ToString() + userId; 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing, though I'm using Jose's LinqSpecs project here: http://linqspecs.codeplex.com/

Comment: sweet, LinqSpecs seems pretty good. I'm in the process of making my specs composable, could save a lot of effort :)

Answer (score 0):

Serializing an expression tree is not something easy. Basically you will need some sort of visitors to inspect all leaf of the expression and convert them to something meaningfull to serialize.

There is no serialization support for expression tree out of the box in .net.

But you can find a good example here:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ExpressionSerializer

It serializes to XML.